# Video stitching Blending in real time

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, image, video, blend-modes

I went through some blending techniques like alpha blending, weighted blending, pyramid blending and Poisson blending and mixture gradient blending.

I have come to a conclusion that pyramid blending cannot be used in real time but don't know whether there are more blending techniques available than these as they are somewhat old?